# How do I add non-mapped elements of a dataframe to the ggplot legend (that contains the mapped elements of the same dataframe)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a dataframe with a total score variable, which is mapped inside a polygon in ggplot. This total score is made of 5 other variables, which I don't want to map. But, how can I add the 5 non-mapped variables to the legend so that these are showing what the total is composed of please?

```
ggplot() +
# Add the basemap tile 
 annotation_map_tile(zoomin = 0, type = "osm") +
 # total score for LSOA layer
 geom_sf(data = alljoined, aes(geometry = minstore$joinlsoageometry, fill = minstore$totscrtot)) +
 # fill layer
 scale_fill_viridis_c(alpha = 0.7) +
 # Legend customisation
 guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Total mean score\nfor area", reverse = TRUE))
```

The above is the map without the 5 variables added to the legend. The 5 variables are contained within the alljoined dataframe, along with a single geometry/polygon.

Comment: We don't have access to your data frame `alljoined` or know the names of the five variables that you want in the legend, so it is hard to help. Can you provide a fully reproducible example?

Comment: Mikael, thank you for looking at this. I am sorry but the only way I can think of to create the data is by providing the folowing link to the github rep' for the data used in the code. I have amended the q-code to relate to this df.
https://github.com/iaincat/ggplot_SO.git